# Proving something is primitive recursive

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, computability

I'm trying to prove $f(n) = 2n$ is primitive recursive. I understand that for something to be primitive recursive it must have the following properties:

$0(x)=x$ the zero function

$s(x)= x+1$ the successor

$p^i (x1,...x2,x3)= xi =$ projection

So would the primitive recursive definition of $f(n)=2n$:

$f(2,n)$

$s(2*f(x))$

$p^i (2)$

Is this correct? If not could someone give me an intuitive explanation? I'm really struggling to understand this!

Thank you in advance!

**----EDIT: 
Ive now got a different answer: 
$f(0,m)$
$f(2,n)=f(mult(2,n))$**

Answer (score 3):

According to wikipedia, we can construct a $1$-ary function $h$ by primitive recursion given a $0$-ary function $f$ and a $2$-ary function $g$ such that $h(0)=f()$ and $h(s(y))=g(y,h(y))$. We can denote this $h=PR(f,g)$. Thus, we can construct $h(n)=2n$ if $f()=0()$ and $g(y,n)=n+2=s(s(n))$. Now we just have to lace these all together:

$$f=PR(0,s\circ s\circ p_2^2),$$

or equivalently,

$$f(0)=0\\f(s(n))=s(s(p_2^2(n,f(n))))=s(s(f(n)))=f(n)+2$$

Here $p_2^2$ is the $2$-ary projection function $p_2^2(y,n)=n$, so that $s\circ s\circ p_2^2(y,n)=n+2$ as desired.

Comment: um um um um um um um um What?!

Comment: @joker You're gonna have to give me more than that if you need me to improve my explanation. What exactly is giving you trouble? I would also recommend reading the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function) if you haven't already.

Answer (score 1):

Among others, if $g$ is primitive recursive and $a$ a constant, then the function $f$ defined by the recursion (hence the name) 
$$ f(0)=a,\qquad f(s(n))=g(f(n))$$
is also primitive recursive.
Try this with $a=0$ and $g(x)=s(s(x))$.

Comment: Is my answer correct?